# (31,16): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `)', `,', `;', `[', or `='

Tags: android, css, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unityscript

The script I have is for to pause and unpause the gameobject . I have two of the same errors  (31,16): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting`)', `,',`;', `[', or`='

I am just trying to pause and unpause the gameobject . Maybe pause and unpause more in my scene . I need the gameobject pause for a couple of seconds and unpause . Dont what to pause the gameobject by a key. Here is my script :

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class star : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject[] pauseObjects;


    void Start () {
    pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    }

void Pause(){
  StartCoroutine(waitToUnpause);
}

IENumerator waitToUnpause(){
  //do the thing to pause game
  Time.timeScale = 7f;//or some other method
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);///or any duration you want
  Time.timeScale = 1f;//or some other method
}

void pauseGameobject()

{
 timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
if(timeLeft < 0)
gameObject.SetActive(false);
{

start coroutine("wait");

}

}

public ienumenator wait()

{

time.timescale = 0;

yield return new waitforsceonds(7);

time.timesale = 1;

}
void pauseGameobject()

{

if(timerleft < 0)

{

start coroutine("wait");

}

}

public ienumenator wait()

{

time.timescale = 0;

yield return new waitforsceonds(7);

time.timesale = 1;

}

}
```

Comment: Did you copy that code? If so, you have some syntax errors in there, aside he ones you get with the unexpected symbol stuff. E.g. in `pauseGameobject`, the `gameObject.SetActive(false)` should be after the `{`, not before (inside the if). Also some stuff like wrong upper/lower case or spaces where they shouldn't be.

Comment: If that isn't the exact code, copy it from the file and insert it, you can use the stackoverflow code command (the {}-icon), also proper indention and the respective line numbers of the errors (so we don't have to count in a longer code) helps.

Comment: I thought I did that.

Comment: Can you test the code ?

Comment: Well, as mentioned, just from looking at your posted code I can tell that it will not compile for a lot of reasons (syntax errors).

Comment: And you don't actually put the `{}` to format the code, just click on that icon or indent it by marking it and pressing `ctrl + k`.

Comment: I just redid it .

Comment: You still have an enormous number of typos in this code. Please consider looking at it through a serviceable IDE to track down where they all occur, fix them, then come back here and update your question if the code still fails to work - Stack Overflow is not intended to provide this kind of service.

Answer (score 0):

This code is compiling without errors (yours is pretty ... unclean). It will definitely not work though. Also I changed some naming to match naming conventions (lower/upper case).

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class Star : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject[] pauseObjects;

    // I guess this variable is meant to be a field
    // it is never set to any initial value!
    float timeLeft;

    void Start () {
        pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    }

    void Pause(){
        StartCoroutine(WaitToUnpause());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitToUnpause(){
        //do the thing to pause game
        Time.timeScale = 7f;//or some other method
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);///or any duration you want
        Time.timeScale = 1f;//or some other method
    }

    void PauseGameobject()

    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeLeft < 0)
        {

            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(Wait());

        }

    }

    public IEnumerator Wait()

    {

        Time.timeScale = 0;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);

        Time.timeScale = 1;

    }

// The following code is nearly a duplicate of the above two functions

//  void PauseGameobject()
//
//  {
//
//      if(timeleft < 0)
//
//      {
//
    //          StartCoroutine(Wait());
//
//      }
//
//  }
//
//  public IEnumerator Wait()
//
//  {
//
//      Time.timeScale = 0;
//
//      yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
//
//      Time.timeScale = 1;
//
//  }

}
```